# Программа для кодирования/декодирования текста при помощи Кода Хэмминга

Tags: python-3.x, кодировка

Есть программа, но выполняется с ошибками. В кодировании она с ошибками переводит слово в биты и в итоге неправильно находит контрольные биты.
Т.е при вводе фразы: Ahoj Hammingu!  программа выдает результат:

```
100010010001
010011011000
110111001111
100011001010
010101000000
000110011000
110111010001
000111011101
000111011101
010111001001
110011011110
010111010111
010011100101
010001010001
```

хотя должен быть результат:

```
001000010010
010100100110
011111100110
110010100110
010000010100
000100110010
011000000110
111001100110
111001100110
101100100110
100111100110
101011000110
101101011110
101000010100
```

Часть кода отвечающего за кодирование:

```
 import random

    CHUNK_LENGTH = 8


    assert not CHUNK_LENGTH % 8

    CHECK_BITS = [i for i in range(1, CHUNK_LENGTH + 1) if not i & (i - 1)]

    def chars_to_bin(chars):

        assert not len(chars) * 8 % CHUNK_LENGTH
        return ''.join([bin(ord(c))[2:].zfill(8) for c in chars])

    def chunk_iterator(text_bin, chunk_size=CHUNK_LENGTH):
        for i in range(len(text_bin)):
            if not i % chunk_size:
                yield text_bin[i:i + chunk_size]

    def get_check_bits_data(value_bin):
        check_bits_count_map = {k: 0 for k in CHECK_BITS}
        for index, value in enumerate(value_bin, 1):
            if int(value):
                bin_char_list = list(bin(index)[2:].zfill(8))
                bin_char_list.reverse()
                for degree in [2 ** int(i) for i, value in enumerate(bin_char_list) if int(value)]:
                    check_bits_count_map[degree] += 1
        check_bits_value_map = {}
        for check_bit, count in check_bits_count_map.items():
            check_bits_value_map[check_bit] = 0 if not count % 2 else 1
        return check_bits_value_map

    def set_empty_check_bits(value_bin):
        for bit in CHECK_BITS:
            value_bin = value_bin[:bit - 1] + '0' + value_bin[bit - 1:]
        return value_bin


    def set_check_bits(value_bin):
        value_bin = set_empty_check_bits(value_bin)
        check_bits_data = get_check_bits_data(value_bin)
        for check_bit, bit_value in check_bits_data.items():
            value_bin = '{0}{1}{2}'.format(
                value_bin[:check_bit - 1], bit_value, value_bin[check_bit:])
        return value_bin

    def encode(source):
        text_bin = chars_to_bin(source)
        result = ''
        for chunk_bin in chunk_iterator(text_bin):
            chunk_bin = set_check_bits(chunk_bin)
            result += chunk_bin
        return result


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        source = input()
        encoded = encode(source)
        print('{0}\n'.format(encoded))
```

Comment: Открыть любой текстовый редактор и начать писать программный код. Какие конкретно проблемы возникают?

Comment: *"Есть программа, но выполняется с ошибками."* -- приведите пример конкретного ввода, соответствующего ожидаемого точного  вывода и опишите что вместо этого происходит подробно. Не нужно приводить весь код, который у вас есть без разбора. Создайте минимальный (но полный) пример кода, который демонстрирует проблему и обновите вопрос [mcve]